# How to get first 16 fames from a video using ffmpeg?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, mp4

I have a video mp4 file(5 seconds duration), it has 125 frames. I need to extract **first 16 continuous frames** into a folder. Can you please put the code for extracting first 16 frames?

I tried -

```
cmd = 'ffmpeg -i {} -frames:v 16 {}/%d.png'.format('/content/drive/MyDrive/MTP/train/X/X0.mp4', '/content/drive/MyDrive/MTP/sample') 
subprocess.call(cmd, shell = True)
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-frames:v` / `-vframes`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -frames:v 16 output_%02d.png
```

Also see the [image muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2).

Comment: The command is not working can you recheck once. I mean the above returns 1 which means failure.

Comment: @SRIVINODPALACHARLA My example command is correct. Check that ffmpeg is actually being executed. Show the complete log from the ffmpeg process.